Something went wrong in my using of FFTW3, on windows system using vscode and MinGW, c++
I am a starter for c++ programing, and I recently need to use the FFTW3. So I download the pre-compiled version for Windows-64 from the official website, using the dlltool -d libfftw3-3.def libfttw3-3.lib -D libfftw3-3.dll to create the .lib file.
Then I ask GPT to generate a simple program of FFT. The program is successfully compiled, however when I excute the .exe, nothing happened, even the cout << "Program start" << endl; cannot work.
The code:
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <fftw3.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Program start." << endl;

    const int N = 100;
    std::vector<double> x(N), y(N);
    
    // define the orginal signal
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        x[i] = i;
        y[i] = std::sin(2 * M_PI * i / N);
    }

    // state the FFT input array
    fftw_complex* y_in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
    fftw_complex* y_out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
    fftw_complex* y_origin = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);

    // Initialize FFT input array
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        y_in[i][0] = y[i];  // Real part
        y_in[i][1] = 0.0;   // Imaginary part
    }

    // create Fourier transformation plans
    fftw_plan plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, y_in, y_out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_plan plan_backward = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, y_out, y_origin, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    // Fourier transformation
    fftw_execute(plan_forward);

    // Inverse Fourier transformation
    fftw_execute(plan_backward);

    // normalization
    std::vector<double> y_reconstructed(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        y_reconstructed[i] = y_origin[i][0] / N;
    }

    // release the FFTW plans
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan_forward);
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan_backward);
    fftw_free(y_in);
    fftw_free(y_out);
    fftw_free(y_origin);

    cout << "Program end." << endl;

    return 0;
}

I use g++ -O2 -g -o a.exe a.cpp -I "C:/fftw" -L "C:/fftw" -lfftw3-3 to compile the program.
I tried to add some more cout but still nothing happened. I think it might be wrong when I link to the fftw?
Update:
I used GDB to run the a.exe, and it turns out some problems:
[New Thread 19440.0x25e4]
[New Thread 19440.0x36a4]
[New Thread 19440.0x5140]
[Thread 19440.0x5140 exited with code 3221225781]
[Thread 19440.0x57e8 exited with code 3221225781]
[Thread 19440.0x36a4 exited with code 3221225781]
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.

I thought maybe the compiler did not find the .dll file

"even the cout << "Program start" << endl; cannot work." - So, is the involvment of FFTW needed? Try to solve that problem without fftw first.

I mean, if I write a simple "hello_world" program , it would not go wrong. This is the first time I use not "header only" library, so I thought it might be the linking to fftw went wrong.

The linking is probably fine. Hmm, ok, I'll get back in a few hours unless someone else has figured it out by then.

You are right, it seems not the linking problem. I comment out all the code which associated with fftw, only left 'cout << "Program start." << endl;', still compile it with g++ -O2 -g -o a.exe a.cpp -I "C:/fftw" -L "C:/fftw" -lfftw3-3. The program will print out normally.
So, It might be something wrong in the fftw lines. I'll check the official document again.

I rechecked GPT, and it told me to put the .dll file should be put to the same directory of a.exe. And it works, maybe I just lack common sense of computers.

That works on Windows, but the equivalent action would not work on Linux, so I don't think you lack common sense. What you do need to do is research the different ways that shared libraries (or DLLs in Windows speak) are located. Putting the DLL in the same directory as the executable is common enough but not the only option.
